# Looking up a list of keys in a <key, value> pair list

Tags: algorithm

I have a list A of elements which are pairs of `<key, value>`. This list is very big. I have another list, B, which is an array of specific keys. I want to read the values associated with keys in array B. What is the best optimized possible solution? For example, I have the following pairs list:

```
A = {<1, a>, <2, b>, <4, c>, <3, d>, <5, h>, <11, k>}
```

I want to find the values for

```
B = {4, 11, 5}
```

which are

```
V = {< 4, c>, <11, k>, <5, h>}
```

I am using C++, and the lists are stored as `std::vector`.

Comment: If you can put your pairs in an unordered_map instead of a vector, that's how you get the lookup as fast as possible. Otherwise merge sort or quick sort + binary search is the best you can do with vectors.

Comment: @Aurast using unordered_map is possible for me. Then, I should just put the pairs in unordered map and get he values for the specific keys?

Comment: An unordered_map maps keys to values, so you don't have to handle pairs explicitly. In a vector, the key is an integer. For example using the key "5" to access a vector like this: vector[5] gets you the fifth element of the vector. For unordered_map, the key isn't an integer, it's the first value of your pair. So if you put the pair <"bob", "john"> into an unordered_map, then unordered_map["bob"] returns "john". "bob" would be in your vector B that you iterate over. To be more specific, you would insert the pair into the map like this: unordered_map["bob"] = "john".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `std::unordered_map` out of the items in array B with keys being the items of array B and values being something special denoting that no value is yet found. Then you can traverse the array A item by item, looking up the `unordered_map` for the key taken from array A and, if the key exists in `unordered_map`, change the value for it in `unordered_map` to the one taken from array A.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the bigger array. Iterate through the smaller array and do a binary search on the bigger array(which is now sorted) for each item. 
You can use the stl's [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and [binary_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) functions which will work pretty well if you have a comparator defined on your key value pair.

Comment: This raises the algorithmic complexity to unnecessary O(N*logN + MlogN) where N is the size of big array A and M is the size of (presumably) small array B. While the task is solvable in O(N*logM) if the big array A is left as is and a balanced tree is built from array B.

Comment: @sergeRogatch that would incur an additional O(N) cost on space since op mentioned he has a vector already

Comment: additional space is O(M) if the number of values matched to the keys from array B is the number of keys or duplicates are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best optimized possible solution?

That's impossible to say without knowing more about your specific situation.

If list A and list B are both very small, your best bet is probably going to be a naive walk through each list for each element. That's `O(m * n)`, but if `m` and `n` are small enough then it's not worth trying anything more complicated.

If the lists are very large, it may be worthwhile to construct a specialized data structure, like a HashMap or HashSet, from their values. This will involve more up-front work, but the overall complexity is `O(m + n)`, so it works out better in the long run.

Depending on what you know about the nature of the keys (e.g. are they unique? What are their upper and lower limits?) you may be able to use a specialized data structure that's even better suited to your needs. The "best" optimized solution will also depend on what you're trying to optimize for: memory usage, number of comparisons, etc.

Ultimately, if performance is really important in this part of your program, you'll want to try a few different techniques and use a profiler or benchmark to get a better idea of what works best.

Comment: The performance is really important for me. Also, I want to have a quick solution for now. Is there any specific STL function or something like that for implementing a fast solution first?

Comment: @mmostajab: I've been away from C++ for too long to be much help there, but it looks like `std::unordered_map` is probably an appropriate data structure. Serge's answer is a good general-purpose approach, which should scale well, especially if your list A doesn't change often, so you can reuse the same `unordered_map` instance when you're querying against it with several different list B instances.